# Time series classification with RNN

Tags: time-series, classification, recurrent-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset of crop yield in 15 years. For each year I have around 5000 samples of classification data. I want to apply RNN to make a prediction in such a way that when I feed the features the crop it predicts also takes into account the previous years.
I applied simple ANN to each year and soon will apply RNN to it but since the data will have 12 samples i don't know what to do. Can you give a basic idea how i should approach the problem?